# $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable if and only if $x + A$ is Lebesgue measurable

Tags: measure-theory

I saw this claim in [Prove that $A$ is Lebesgue measurable implies that $x+A = \{ x+y : y \in A \}$ is measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934245/prove-that-a-is-lebesgue-measurable-implies-that-xa-xy-y-in-a-i)

I don't get the last sentence , why $ m\big( x + B \big) \geq  m\Big( (B + x) \cap (A + x) \Big) + m\Big( (B + x) \cap (x + A^c) \Big)$ implies that $x + A$ is Lebesgue measurable.

**Claim 1**:  $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable if and only if $x + A$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Proof of claim1:  It is enough to show only one direction, since $A = \big( x + A \big) + (-x).$ Suppose $A$ is measurable, then for any $B\subset \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$m\big( B \big) \geq m\big( B \cap A \big) + m\big( B \cap A^c \big) \,\, . $$
Therefore,
$ m\big( x + B \big) \geq  m\big( B \cap A \big) + m\big( B \cap A^c \big) = m\Big( (B + x) \cap (A + x) \Big) + m\Big( (B + x) \cap (x + A^c) \Big)$,
which implies that $x + A$ is Lebesgue measurable.  ___   Q.E.D.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: They are just using the definition of measurability in reverse. For any $V \subset \mathbb R$, if you define $B = -x + V$, then $B + x = V$. Also $(x + A)^c = x + A^c$; now you can apply the definition